# Data to Table in Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vb.net, ms-word, spreadsheet

I was given the assignment of parsing a word document form, and putting it into an Excel sheet. The code below does that with ease.. but I've recently learned I need to put that data into an Excel table instead of just the cells of a sheet.

```
For row = 1 To theTable.Rows.Count   `until end of rows
                isHeaderOrNot = theTable.Cell(row, 0).Range.Text `if first field in row is a header
                If isHeaderOrNot.Contains("Section") Or isHeaderOrNot.Contains("Field") Then Continue For
                keyText = theTable.Cell(row, 2).Range.Text    `gets key text
                valueText = theTable.Cell(row, 3).Range.Text  `gets value text
                cleanStringKey = Regex.Replace(keyText, Chr(7), "") `clean strings
                cleanStringValue = Regex.Replace(valueText, Chr(7), "")


                xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, column) = cleanStringKey `puts key in row 1 and column n
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, column) = cleanStringValue `puts value in row 2 column n

                column = column + 1 `increment column
            Next
```

I was wondering if I would have to completely change my code in order to make it a table... In short go from

[image]

To

[image]

I am completely new to VB.net so if you could, dumb everything down as much as possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just highlight all the data, go to Insert --> Table. And it should automatically format, and you can choose if it has headers, which it looks like you do.

Comment: I'm sure he wants some type of automation as his example shows he knows how to do it manually. If you dim a variable as listobject and set it to your range it will make it into a table. Not sure how that goes in VB but fairly succinct in VBA.

Comment: Yes I'm looking for some type of automation. No idea if it helps or not, but if you click into cell `A1` and then click insert table it creates a table just as I'd like it to out of all of the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823155.aspx) method of [`WorkSheet.ListObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195678.aspx) to create a new list (table).

**Example**

After adding reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` Add this import to the form:

```
Imports XL = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

Then use such code to create a list:

```
Dim Application = New XL.Application()
Application.Visible = True
Dim book = Application.Workbooks.Add()
Dim sheet = DirectCast(book.Worksheets(1), XL.Worksheet)
sheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Product"
sheet.Cells(1, 2) = "Price"
sheet.Cells(2, 1) = "Product 1"
sheet.Cells(2, 2) = "100"
sheet.Cells(3, 1) = "Product 2"
sheet.Cells(3, 2) = "200"
sheet.Cells(4, 1) = "Product 3"
sheet.Cells(4, 2) = "300"
Dim list = sheet.ListObjects.Add( _
                XL.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange, _
                sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(1, 1), sheet.Cells(4, 2)), _
                Type.Missing, XL.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes)
```

Then you will see this result:

[image]

Comment: how to remove the automatic coloring for the table ?

Comment: @AhmedTaha To figure out how to do such things, usually you can record a macro in the excel and see the code of the recorded macro.

Comment: Thank you for replying... I mean how to do this by code. Not by excel itself

Comment: @AhmedTaha When you record a macro in Excel, you can see the source code of recorded macro easily.

Comment: @AhmedTaha You can set `TableStyle` property of the list, for example `list.TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"`. To completely remove the styling, set it to empty string.